# asp.net paypal redirect set value to mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, paypal

I have C# windows form application with button to open default web browser and go to url to buy credits using paypal.

As a description for paypal product I set username of user register via my c# application.
Paypal button url: (I changed paypal email address to paypal@emailadress.com because I do not want to reveal my paypal email.)

```
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?&cmd=_xclick&business=paypal@emailaddress.com&currency_code=EUR&amount=" + this.textBox1.Text + "&item_name=" + Form1.sendusername + "";
```

[image: when button is pressed you are redirected to paypal (description top left is username of c# user]

I need to crate .asp web page for paypal return url. If payment is successful I would like to change value money in mysql database where username is item_name (Form1.sendusername) for old value + new amount.

```
Mysql database structure:
name of mysql database: sqldata
name of table: users
name of row: money
```

i guess something like: update money set sqldata.users where username=item_name ....

Can someone provide me with example that I can edit. Please make it simple for me to understand because I am a noob :) Thanks!

Comment: You need to tag this as asp.net, not classic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [PayPal REST API SDK](http://paypal.github.io/). There are good, simple, examples on the Github repository.